# Delete duplicate records by column 1 but having differ values in column 2 and column 3

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table like:

```
SSN FName   LName
1   a   b
1   a   b
1   b   b -------------> to delete
2   c   d
2   c   d
```

as above example I want to delete such records where `SSN` has different values in `FName` and `LName` columns.

Kindly help.

Comment: What happens when there are 3 records for `SSN = 1`, all with different values? Which one is the correct record?

Comment: And why does not the table have a primary key?

Comment: Table is temporary. Actually, need to remove all such records, where SSn is doubtful and have different names on same SSn number.

Comment: Looking for urgent help

Comment: In Question, you have said `I want to delete such records where SSN has different values in FName and LName columns` but in code part it is indicated to delete where `FName` and `LName` are same?

Comment: @vijayp - It appears. but the purpose behind is to show the different name on SSSn 1.

Comment: run this and see if these are the row you want to delete `select SSN, FName,LName from schamaName.TableName where FName != LName`

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you want to keep the rows where the combination of `SSN`, `FName` and `LName` are the most common.

You can do that with an updateable CTE that counts the number of occurrences for each combination using `count() over()` and then enumerates the counts using `rank()`.

```
declare @T table
(
  SSN int,
  FName char(1),
  LName char(1)
);

insert into @T values
(1, 'a', 'b'),
(1, 'a', 'b'),
(1, 'b', 'b'), -------------> to delete
(2, 'c', 'd'),
(2, 'c', 'd'),
(3, 'a', 'b'),
(3, 'c', 'd');

with C1 as
(
  select T.SSN,
         count(*) over(partition by T.SSN, T.FName, T.LName) as C
  from @T as T
), C2 as
(
  select rank() over(partition by C1.SSN order by C1.C desc) as RN
  from C1
)
delete from C2
where C2.RN > 1;

select *
from @T;
```

Result:

```
SSN         FName LName
----------- ----- -----
1           a     b
1           a     b
2           c     d
2           c     d
3           a     b
3           c     d
```

In the case where there is a tie for most common combination (SSN = 3) the above query will keep all the rows for the tie.